# Python: to wrap functions via lambda

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator, lambda

I have some code like

```
class EventHandler:
    def handle(self, event):
        pass

def wrap_handler(handler):
    def log_event(proc, e):
        print e
        proc(e)
    handler.handle = lambda e: log_event(handler.handle, e)

handler = EventHandler()
wrap_handler(handler)
handler.handle('event')
```

that will end up with infinite recursion. While changing `wrap_handler` to

```
def wrap_handler(handler):
    def log_event(proc, e):
        print e
        proc(e)
    # handler.handle = lambda e: log_event(handler.handle, e)
    handle_func = handler.handle
    handler.handle = lambda e: log_event(handle_func, e)
```

the program will become OK. Why is that? And could anyone tell me more common ways to wrap functions?

Comment: Usually you wrap functions using decorators...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It ends in an infinite recursion as when `lambda e: log_event(handler.handle, e)` is called, `handler.handle` is already the *lambda* expression. `log_event` would call the *lambda* and the *lambda* would call `log_event`, etc..

To fix this, just save the current method in the local-scope, this also does not need the additional lambda-expression.

```
class EventHandler:
    def handle(self, event):
        pass

def wrap_handler(handler):
    proc = handler.handle
    def log_event(e):
        print e
        proc(e)
    handler.handle = log_event

handler = EventHandler()
wrap_handler(handler)
handler.handle('event')
```

You could also use a decorator.

```
def logging(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Calling %s with:" % function.__name__, args, kwargs
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class EventHandler:
    @ logging
    def handle(self, event):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "EventHandler instance"

handler = EventHandler()
handler.handle('event')
```

> C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>foo.py
>   Calling handle with: (EventHandler instance, 'event') {}

Answer (score 2):

Because functions are objects, you do not need to use a lambda to assign them to a variable. Instead do:

```
def wrap_handler(handler):
    proc = handler.handle
    def log_event(e):
        print e
        proc(e)
    # handler.handle = lambda e: log_event(handler.handle, e)
    handler.handle = log_event
```

In that code, you avoid evaluating handler.handle in log_event, so no recursion occurs.

It's a little bit more usual to use decorators, but decorators will do much the same thing internally.

Comment: This will result in a *NameError* as no variable named `e` is available. Also, this would execute the function and assign it's return-value, and it will not assign the whole function.

Comment: And there is no `proc` (called inside `log_event`).

Comment: @yak: Seriously, explain yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
handler.handle = lambda e: log_event(handler.handle, e)
```

The anonymous function will, upon invocation, look up `handler`'s `handle` member and pass that (along with `e`) to `log_event`. Because you immediately set `handler.handle` to the anonymous function, the anonymous function just gets a reference to itself.

This on the other hand:

```
handle_func = handler.handle
handler.handle = lambda e: log_event(handle_func, e)
```

Gets the `handler`'s method once (specifically, you get a "bound method" object gluing the object and the underlying function object together), and only then you create the anonymous function and overwrite `handler.handle`.